# How can I refer to the checked property of an element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to refer to the checked property of checkbox in jQuery. It will only return if I refer to `this` inside an event handler on the element:

```
$("#chkACCEPT").click ->
  alert this.checked                   // returns true
  alert $("#chkACCEPT").checked        // returns undefined
```

Why does the second line return `undefined`? That seems so crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `jQuery` *object* doesn't have `.checked` property, but pure `DOM` *object* does.

So if you want to use `.checked` you can use `this`, or pull a native `DOM` object from `jQuery`:

```
alert(this.checked)   or  alert ($("#chkACCEPT")[0].checked)
```

**Or with jQuery, using**  **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** **:**

```
$(this).prop('checked'); // $("#chkACCEPT").prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

`.checked` is property associated to javascript object and not jquery object. For using it on jquery object you need to convert it to JS object and then use `checked` property

```
 $("#chkACCEPT")[0].checked
```

Correct way to do this is:

Using javascript:

```
$("#chkACCEPT").click(function(){
  console.log(this.checked); //return bool value
});
```

Using Jquery:

```
$("#chkACCEPT").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).is(':checked'));//return bool value
});
```